# Validation Check in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, amazon-redshift

I am performing a validation check on a staging table in Airflow. If that condition is met I then perform an upsert on the destination table. For instances where there is 1 staging table and 1 destination table it works. My problem is when I have to perform the same validation on more than 1 staging table before upserting to the destination table associated with those staging tables. Below is the work I have currently done:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
from airflow.hooks.postgres_hook import PostgresHook
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 10, 22),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'email_on_success': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'task_concurrency': 1
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my_upsert_dag',
    schedule_interval='0 6 * * 1-6',
    concurrency=64,
    tags=['DEV', 'STAGE'],
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False
)

def check_count(staging_table, upsert_table, **kwargs):
    redshift_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id='redshift_conn')
    count_query = f"SELECT COUNT(0) FROM {staging_table} WHERE processed_flag = 'N'"
    count_result = redshift_hook.get_first(count_query)[0]
    print(count_result)
    if count_result > 0:
        return f'upsert_task_{upsert_table}'
    else:
        return 'pass'

# Dummy start task
start = DummyOperator(
    task_id="start",
    dag=dag
)

# Dummy end task
end = DummyOperator(
    task_id="end",
    trigger_rule='none_failed_or_skipped',
    dag=dag
)

# List of staging and upsert tables (example: add more tables to this list)
tables = [
    ('test1_stg', 'test1'),
    ('test2_stg', 'test2')
]

# Create a dictionary to store tasks based on table names
tasks = {}

# Task to check the staging table for unprocessed records and branch based on the result
for staging_table, upsert_table in tables:
    check_task = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id=f'check_task_{staging_table}',
        python_callable=check_count,
        do_xcom_push=False,
        op_args=[staging_table, upsert_table],
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag
    )
    
    upsert_task = PostgresOperator(
        task_id=f'upsert_task_{upsert_table}',
        sql=f"sql/upsert_{upsert_table}.sql",
        postgres_conn_id='redshift_cpdw', 
        dag=dag,
    )

    # Dummy pass task
    pass_task = DummyOperator(
        task_id= f'pass_task_{upsert_table}',
        dag=dag
    )

    # Store tasks in the dictionary
    tasks[f'check_task_{staging_table}'] = check_task
    tasks[f'upsert_task_{upsert_table}'] = upsert_task
    tasks[f'pass_task_{upsert_table}'] = pass_task


    start >> check_task >> [upsert_task, pass_task] >> end
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem or error you're seeing with more than one staging table?